# Samba: Need guest/everyone read-only and writeable by users in group

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I can't get this to work correctly. I can login as guest fine but when I enter the username and password for a user on the server, it doesn't accept it. Not even root.

smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server Version %v

    # log files split per-machine:
    log level = 2
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    # maximum size of 50KB per log file, then rotate:
    max log size = 50
    debug timestamp = yes

    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam

    map to guest = bad user

[public]
    comment = Public Stuff
    path = /opt/shares/filerepo
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    write list = +samba
```

The user is `filerepo`.

/etc/passwd:

```
filerepo:x:1000:1001::/home/filerepo:/bin/bash
```

The group info:

```
$ groups filerepo
filerepo : filerepo samba
```

The permissions for the shared directory (`ls -lZ /opt/shares/`):

```
drwxrwxr-x. filerepo samba unconfined_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 filerepo
```

Samba Service:

```
$ systemctl status smb.service
smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-04-24 13:21:52 PDT; 4s ago
 Main PID: 19684 (smbd)
   Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/smb.service
           ├─19684 /usr/sbin/smbd
           └─19685 /usr/sbin/smbd

Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain smbd[19683]: [2015/04/24 13:21:52.516358,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1269(main)
Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain smbd[19683]: standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain smbd[19684]: [2015/04/24 13:21:52.522356,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:136(daemon_ready)
Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB Daemon.
Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain smbd[19684]: STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsFailed to fetch record!
Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain smbd[19686]: STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsUnable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Transport endpoint is not connected
Apr 24 13:21:52 localhost.localdomain smbd[19685]: STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsfailed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Firewall:

```
$ systemctl status firewalld
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2015-04-24 13:00:08 PDT; 25min ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking through my logs `/var/log/samba/log.xxxxxxx` I saw the line

```
check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [filerepo] -> [filerepo] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
```

Although I added the linux user/password, I didn't add the samba one.

To get it working I had to do: `smbpassword -a filerepo` and set a password for the samba user.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Could you expand your answer to elaborate a little to make the answer more useful to others with a similar problem?  Thanks.  BTW, in two days, you will be able to accept your own answer, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily disable SElinux (after reboot SELinux will be enabled):

```
setenforce 0
```

or

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

If this works (Samba works fine), setup Samba with SELinux, example: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba#head-86233024cba06a1e4f554e763a2f634a61eae9b8

P.S. Don't disable SELinux forever, it is not true way.